# Average completion rate per day from PHP array of dates

Tags: php

So I have an array of dates which correspond to the date an article was marked "read"/complete.

What I'm trying to achieve is find the average read rate per day, per week and per month.

Ideally what I'd like to have is "On average you read X articles per day".

This code is where I build the array:

```
$timeRead = $key["time_read"];
$dateRead = date('m/d/Y', $timeRead);
array_push($readDatesArray, $dateRead);
```

I understand I need to loop over the array and then need to group by date and then get an average somehow. Would really appreciate some help!

```
foreach ($readDatesArray as $key) {
    echo $key . "<br>";
}
```

The array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 07/14/2014
    [1] => 07/13/2014
    [2] => 07/12/2014
    [3] => 07/12/2014
    [4] => 07/12/2014
    [5] => 07/12/2014
    [6] => 07/12/2014
    [7] => 07/11/2014
    [8] => 07/11/2014
    [9] => 07/11/2014
    [10] => 07/10/2014
    [11] => 07/09/2014
    [12] => 07/11/2014
    [13] => 07/09/2014
    [14] => 07/09/2014
    [15] => 07/09/2014
    [16] => 07/09/2014
    [17] => 07/09/2014
    [18] => 07/05/2014
    [19] => 07/04/2014
    [20] => 07/05/2014
    [21] => 07/05/2014
    [22] => 07/05/2014
    [23] => 07/04/2014
    [24] => 07/02/2014
    [25] => 07/02/2014
    [26] => 07/02/2014
    [27] => 07/04/2014
    [28] => 07/02/2014
    [29] => 07/02/2014
    [30] => 06/29/2014
    [31] => 06/29/2014
    [32] => 06/29/2014
    [33] => 06/29/2014
    [34] => 06/24/2014
    [35] => 06/29/2014
    [36] => 06/20/2014
    [37] => 06/20/2014
    [38] => 06/14/2014
    [39] => 06/07/2014
    [40] => 06/07/2014
    [41] => 06/05/2014
    [42] => 06/05/2014
    [43] => 06/05/2014
    [44] => 06/03/2014
    [45] => 06/07/2014
    [46] => 06/05/2014
    [47] => 05/31/2014
    [48] => 05/31/2014
    [49] => 06/05/2014
    [50] => 05/28/2014
    [51] => 05/20/2014
    [52] => 07/09/2014
    [53] => 05/10/2014
    [54] => 05/10/2014
    [55] => 05/10/2014
    [56] => 05/10/2014
    [57] => 05/03/2014
    [58] => 05/03/2014
    [59] => 05/03/2014
    [60] => 04/24/2014
    [61] => 04/20/2014
    [62] => 05/28/2014
    [63] => 04/20/2014
    [64] => 04/20/2014
    [65] => 04/20/2014
    [66] => 04/18/2014
    [67] => 04/18/2014
    [68] => 04/12/2014
    [69] => 04/20/2014
    [70] => 04/02/2014
    [71] => 04/20/2014
    [72] => 03/27/2014
    [73] => 04/02/2014
    [74] => 04/02/2014
    [75] => 03/27/2014
    [76] => 03/16/2014
    [77] => 03/16/2014
    [78] => 03/16/2014
    [79] => 03/16/2014
    [80] => 03/16/2014
    [81] => 03/02/2014
    [82] => 03/02/2014
    [83] => 03/02/2014
    [84] => 02/16/2014
    [85] => 02/16/2014
    [86] => 02/10/2014
    [87] => 02/22/2014
    [88] => 02/10/2014
    [89] => 02/23/2014
    [90] => 03/02/2014
    [91] => 03/16/2014
    [92] => 03/16/2014
    [93] => 03/16/2014
    [94] => 01/13/2014
    [95] => 01/13/2014
    [96] => 01/13/2014
    [97] => 01/08/2014
    [98] => 01/08/2014
    [99] => 01/08/2014
    [100] => 01/08/2014
    [101] => 05/28/2014
    [102] => 03/27/2014
    [103] => 03/27/2014
    [104] => 03/27/2014
    [105] => 03/27/2014
    [106] => 01/08/2014
    [107] => 03/27/2014
    [108] => 03/27/2014
    [109] => 03/27/2014
    [110] => 03/27/2014
    [111] => 12/15/2013
    [112] => 12/15/2013
    [113] => 12/19/2013
    [114] => 03/27/2014
    [115] => 03/27/2014
    [116] => 12/15/2013
    [117] => 12/15/2013
    [118] => 12/15/2013
    [119] => 12/15/2013
    [120] => 03/27/2014
    [121] => 03/27/2014
    [122] => 12/15/2013
    [123] => 12/15/2013
    [124] => 12/15/2013
    [125] => 03/27/2014
    [126] => 12/15/2013
    [127] => 12/15/2013
    [128] => 03/27/2014
    [129] => 12/15/2013
    [130] => 12/15/2013
    [131] => 03/27/2014
    [132] => 03/27/2014
    [133] => 12/15/2013
    [134] => 03/16/2014
    [135] => 12/05/2013
    [136] => 12/15/2013
    [137] => 03/27/2014
    [138] => 03/27/2014
    [139] => 12/15/2013
    [140] => 03/27/2014
    [141] => 12/15/2013
    [142] => 12/15/2013
    [143] => 03/27/2014
    [144] => 12/03/2013
    [145] => 12/03/2013
    [146] => 12/03/2013
    [147] => 12/03/2013
    [148] => 12/03/2013
    [149] => 12/03/2013
    [150] => 12/01/2013
    [151] => 12/01/2013
    [152] => 12/03/2013
    [153] => 12/03/2013
    [154] => 12/03/2013
    [155] => 12/03/2013
    [156] => 12/03/2013
    [157] => 11/30/2013
    [158] => 11/30/2013
    [159] => 12/03/2013
    [160] => 11/30/2013
    [161] => 12/03/2013
    [162] => 12/03/2013
    [163] => 12/03/2013
    [164] => 03/27/2014
    [165] => 11/30/2013
    [166] => 11/30/2013
    [167] => 12/03/2013
    [168] => 12/03/2013
    [169] => 12/03/2013
    [170] => 11/30/2013
    [171] => 11/30/2013
    [172] => 11/30/2013
    [173] => 03/27/2014
    [174] => 03/27/2014
    [175] => 11/30/2013
    [176] => 11/22/2013
    [177] => 11/30/2013
    [178] => 11/30/2013
    [179] => 11/30/2013
    [180] => 11/30/2013
    [181] => 11/30/2013
    [182] => 12/03/2013
    [183] => 11/30/2013
    [184] => 11/30/2013
    [185] => 11/16/2013
    [186] => 11/16/2013
    [187] => 11/15/2013
    [188] => 11/15/2013
    [189] => 11/15/2013
    [190] => 11/15/2013
    [191] => 11/15/2013
    [192] => 11/15/2013
    [193] => 05/28/2014
    [194] => 11/15/2013
    [195] => 11/15/2013
    [196] => 11/09/2013
    [197] => 11/09/2013
    [198] => 11/15/2013
    [199] => 11/07/2013
    [200] => 04/18/2014
    [201] => 11/23/2013
    [202] => 11/03/2013
    [203] => 11/03/2013
    [204] => 11/01/2013
    [205] => 10/27/2013
    [206] => 10/27/2013
    [207] => 10/29/2013
    [208] => 10/27/2013
    [209] => 10/27/2013
    [210] => 10/27/2013
    [211] => 05/28/2014
    [212] => 10/29/2013
    [213] => 10/25/2013
    [214] => 10/29/2013
    [215] => 10/29/2013
    [216] => 10/29/2013
    [217] => 10/29/2013
    [218] => 10/25/2013
    [219] => 12/03/2013
    [220] => 10/20/2013
    [221] => 10/20/2013
    [222] => 10/20/2013
    [223] => 10/20/2013
    [224] => 12/30/2013
    [225] => 10/20/2013
    [226] => 11/19/2013
    [227] => 10/20/2013
    [228] => 10/16/2013
    [229] => 10/15/2013
    [230] => 10/20/2013
    [231] => 10/16/2013
    [232] => 10/16/2013
    [233] => 10/11/2013
    [234] => 10/11/2013
    [235] => 10/11/2013
    [236] => 10/10/2013
    [237] => 10/09/2013
    [238] => 12/15/2013
    [239] => 10/08/2013
    [240] => 10/08/2013
    [241] => 10/07/2013
    [242] => 10/06/2013
    [243] => 10/06/2013
    [244] => 11/03/2013
    [245] => 10/06/2013
    [246] => 10/06/2013
    [247] => 10/06/2013
    [248] => 10/06/2013
    [249] => 10/07/2013
    [250] => 10/04/2013
    [251] => 10/02/2013
    [252] => 10/04/2013
    [253] => 03/16/2014
    [254] => 11/03/2013
    [255] => 10/06/2013
    [256] => 11/03/2013
    [257] => 09/30/2013
    [258] => 09/30/2013
    [259] => 10/06/2013
    [260] => 09/29/2013
    [261] => 09/29/2013
    [262] => 09/29/2013
    [263] => 09/30/2013
    [264] => 09/29/2013
    [265] => 04/02/2014
    [266] => 09/30/2013
    [267] => 09/28/2013
    [268] => 09/28/2013
    [269] => 09/28/2013
    [270] => 09/28/2013
    [271] => 09/25/2013
    [272] => 09/25/2013
    [273] => 09/25/2013
    [274] => 09/25/2013
    [275] => 09/25/2013
    [276] => 09/25/2013
    [277] => 09/25/2013
    [278] => 09/25/2013
    [279] => 09/25/2013
    [280] => 09/25/2013
    [281] => 09/25/2013
    [282] => 03/17/2013
    [283] => 03/17/2013
    [284] => 02/18/2013
    [285] => 09/25/2013
    [286] => 09/25/2013
    [287] => 09/25/2013
    [288] => 02/01/2013
    [289] => 02/01/2013
    [290] => 02/01/2013
    [291] => 02/01/2013
    [292] => 01/27/2013
    [293] => 01/27/2013
    [294] => 09/25/2013
    [295] => 09/25/2013
    [296] => 09/25/2013
    [297] => 02/01/2013
    [298] => 09/25/2013
    [299] => 09/25/2013
    [300] => 09/25/2013
    [301] => 09/25/2013
    [302] => 09/25/2013
    [303] => 09/25/2013
    [304] => 09/25/2013
    [305] => 09/25/2013
    [306] => 09/25/2013
    [307] => 09/25/2013
    [308] => 09/25/2013
    [309] => 09/25/2013
    [310] => 09/25/2013
    [311] => 09/25/2013
    [312] => 01/20/2013
    [313] => 01/20/2013
    [314] => 01/19/2013
    [315] => 01/19/2013
    [316] => 09/25/2013
    [317] => 09/25/2013
    [318] => 01/20/2013
    [319] => 01/20/2013
    [320] => 09/25/2013
    [321] => 09/25/2013
    [322] => 09/25/2013
    [323] => 09/25/2013
    [324] => 01/17/2013
    [325] => 09/25/2013
    [326] => 09/25/2013
    [327] => 01/17/2013
    [328] => 09/25/2013
    [329] => 09/25/2013
    [330] => 01/15/2013
    [331] => 01/15/2013
    [332] => 01/15/2013
    [333] => 09/25/2013
    [334] => 09/25/2013
    [335] => 09/25/2013
    [336] => 01/15/2013
    [337] => 01/15/2013
    [338] => 01/11/2013
    [339] => 01/11/2013
    [340] => 01/10/2013
    [341] => 01/18/2013
    [342] => 01/11/2013
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well technically it should be this

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');  // Whenever the user joined
$datetime2 = new DateTime();  // Now
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);


$number = (count($readDatesArray)/$interval->days);
echo "On average you read $number articles per day";

$number = (count($readDatesArray)/$interval->weeks);
echo "On average you read $number articles per week";

$number = (count($readDatesArray)/$interval->months);
echo "On average you read $number articles per month";
```

Because they might read 0 books one day. So the array data dates are kind of irrelevant. All that matters is how many books they have actually read.

Comment: Thanks! I just editing my question to show how I build my array - do I need to convert the timestamp into DateTime?

Comment: No - because we are not using the dates in your array. Just "today" and then whatever the start date is (which should probably be when they joined).

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. Just a quick one, how can I solve the "division by 0" issue?

Comment: Since I cannot access the users sign up date from this API - I could set the first date to the date of the first "completion". Might work well :)